# Initialization of cluster taking longer time and sometime throwing error in Azure databricks environment

Tags: jobs, azure-databricks

I have scheduled job to run at specific time in Azure Databricks but i am getting cluster error while it getting initialized.

[image]

Comment: Make sure the resources that you are requesting is within the limit that is assigned.From the error it is clear that only 4 resources are left and you are requesting 8. Can you minimize it to 3 or 4 and give it a try and see if it works.

Comment: Thank you Nikunj for the response.I have configured 8 as workers.You are telling i should reduce it to 3 or 4?

Comment: yes as there are not enough resources available that you can use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to vm quota limit with your subscription . You can resolve this issue by increasing the quota [ref](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/azure/azure-portal/supportability/regional-quota-requests)